# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified) for zipfile in java

Tags: java, zip

Copying the files from subfolder of zipfile to other zipfile subfolder. 
Getting File not found exception at ZipInputStream.
I have checked in source path file is exists. Kindly send me whatever i specified in srcFile path.

```
 File srcFile = new File(sourceFile+ File.separator + versions[j]+ File.separator + folders[l]+ File.separator +entryList[3]);



 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(srcFile));
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                                             zipout.putNextEntry(zEntry);
                                            zipout.write(buffer, 0, len);

                                            }
```

It is showing the path correctly as D:\LAB\archive\8367.zip\1\2l\FS-restore.txt
but getting exception also.

sourceFile is D:\LAB\archive\8367.zip
versions and folders are subfolders name and entryList is file name.

Comment: It should be `ZipFile zis = new ZipFile(new File("D:\\LAB\\archive\\8367.zip"));`, you can the iterator over the `entries` and find the one you're after, see [`ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) for more details

Comment: File srcFile = new File(sourceFile+"\\"+ versions[j]+ "\\" + folders[l]+"\\"+entryList[3]);    I tried like this but its getting same error

Comment: I have to read the file.   while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                                     zipout.putNextEntry(zEntry);
                              zipout.write(buffer, 0, len);}       if  I used ZipFile there is no predefined read method. @ MadProgrammer

Comment: Get a `ZipEntry` from the `ZipFile` (either by name or by using `entries), which you can then ask `ZipFile` for a `InputStream` to read from...

Comment: In InputStream can't accepting the zipentry. zEntry = zin.getNextEntry();  zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zEntry));  I have used like this.

Comment: `ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(new File("D:\\LAB\\archive\\8367.zip"));` `ZipEntry ze = zf.getEntry("1/2l/FS-restore.txt");` `InputStream is = zf.getInputStream(ze);` - This makes assumptions about your zip structure and I would use `ZipFile#entries` to list the contents so you're sure of it's proper name

Comment: It is not working. getting Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: *"This makes assumptions about your zip structure and I would use ZipFile#entries to list the contents so you're sure of it's proper name"*

Comment: zipfile entries list the paths/files in zipfile right? I want to  read the content within that sub files(files within zipfile) separately.

Comment: Yes, but I'm suggesting using entries to print the contents of the zipFile to verify that you've got the path/name right

Comment: Resolved error by using new stream with new zipentry.                          loc_ze = new ZipEntry(zEntry.getName());
                                   zipout.putNextEntry(loc_ze);
                                zipfile = new ZipFile(sourceFile);
                                InputStream stream = zipfile.getInputStream(zEntry); while ((len = stream.read(b)) != -1) 
                                  {    zipout.write(b, 0, len);
                                  }

Answer (score 0):

Resolved error by using new stream with new zipentry. `loc_ze = new ZipEntry(zEntry.getName()); zipout.putNextEntry(loc_ze); zipfile = new ZipFile(sourceFile); InputStream stream = zipfile.getInputStream(zEntry); while ((len = stream.read(b)) != -1) { zipout.write(b, 0, len); }`